# repeat numbers in trial structure

Tags: for-loop, numbers, repeat, psychtoolbox

How can I tell matlab to use numbers again ?

I have 10 Trials but only 8 numbers and I want to tell matlab to repeat the numbers in a randomized order. How can I do this?

numbers = {0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8};

Answer (score 1):

The Psychtoolbox function RandSel can be used for this:

```
numbers = 1:8;
trialNumbers = RandSel(numbers, 10);
```

Note that because the selection is random, on a given run of 10 trials a given number might be repeated several times or not used at all.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was searching for.